# How to resolve "PCH file not found" error coming in the code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I just cloned a github code. 
When i tried to run it , it gave me no bridging header available isse, which i resolved by changing the folder name in "Build settings" .
After that when i tried to build i am getting this issue as

```
"<unknown>:0: error: PCH file '/Users/iosdeveloper/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-ebqolwjodqhfifemlvpiqcmkwmtt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/Project_1CZ4Z98EHTKKG-clang_1PO86BEGEY3JE.pch' not found: module file not found
<unknown>:0: error: clang importer creation failed
"
```

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 8):

In my case I've not included `.h` extension at the end of App-Bridging-Header in Build Settings. After given App-Bridging-Header.h the error gone. Hope it will help to some one.

Answer (score 3):

Use $(SRCROOT)/$(PROJECT_NAME) to setup a dynamic link as dragging the file to settings make a static path and that causes a problem when running the project in another path

go to

1- Build Settings > Search: "Prefix Header".

2- Under "Apple LLVM 7.0" you will get the Prefix Header key.

3- Type file directory. e.g: "$(SRCROOT)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/ProjectName-Prefix.pch".

Answer (score 1):

I too had this issue today - I found that if I gave the path to my `App-Bridging-Header.h` in the form of `"${SRCROOT}/App/Some/Directory/App-Bridging-Header.h"` the error in question would occur, however by changing the bridging header path to simply `App/Some/Directory/App-Bridging-Header.h` the PCH "module file not found" disappeared and I was able to compile my project.

I did not need to create a `Prefix.pch` file at all

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: This ended up being the problem for me as well. After some massive file reorganization using Synx, I manually added `$(SRCROOT)` into my bridging header path. After removing it, my build started working again. Thanks!