# xcode can't find .phc file after git clone

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, git

we are working on a project and after the latest commit and push and cloning I get the error and can't figure it out by the answers given in other questions. here is my code:

**:0: error: PCH file '/Users/massoudhasanzade/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UstaTap-ecwxkladaezcotgdfsvtzamhyqra/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/libs-swift_2WQNLP8TV3ZDQ-clang_FLOQM2IRAN30.pch' not found: module file not found
:0: error: clang importer creation failed**

I tried cleaning build folder, clean project, delete whole derived data and other options but its just not working!

Comment: also I am not using any precompiled headers I can't find any connection here!

Comment: This looks similar:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48290169/how-to-resolve-pch-file-not-found-error-coming-in-the-code

I think those files are generated to be able to access Swift code from objc.